# How can I share form values between two instances of same form in react-final-form

Tags: reactjs, react-state, react-final-form

Lets say I have two child components of the form (`react-final-form`) and when one updates I want to pass the certain updated values that have same field names to the second one.
So for example if the field with name 'morningTea'

```
<Field name="morningTea" component="input"></Field>
```

updates when inputting the value(not on submit) then the reflected change should also be seen in the respective field with name `morningTea` in second form.

I reproduced my problem here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-final-form-accessing-other-field-values-forked-y617kb?file=/index.js:1139-1194